# Text over image when hovering

Tags: html, css, text, hover

I want to be able to make text appear over image upon hover without the current effects effecting the text boxes can anyone please assist me with this?

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
      -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: #4d4d4d4d;
}

.pic {
  border: 0px solid #55009f;  
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

/*MORPH*/
.morph {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
     -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
       -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
      -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
          transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.morph:hover {
-webkit-transform:translate(0px,-10px);
-webkit-filter:grayscale(100%) blur(1px);
}
```

```html
<link rel="Stylesheet" href="Stylesheet.css">
<div class="morph pic">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/sports/1" alt="cricket">
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is known as imagetooltip

Visit

http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex4/imagetooltip.htm

Everything including the demonstration, code and files are there.

Comment: In future, please don't provide links to other places before some code or example, that is not an answer :)

Comment: @MarkoMackic but if you pay a visit to the webpage, you'll see the amount of features this code offers isn't possibly a great idea to paste it in here and they have done a much better job at organizing the code. and if it provides solution to one's question, it's definitely known as an "answer"

Answer (score 1):

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
      -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: #4d4d4d4d;
}
.morph{
 height: 200px;
 width: 200px;
 text-align:center;
 margin:0
}
.pic {
  border: 0px solid #55009f;  
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

/*MORPH*/
.pic{
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
     -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
       -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
      -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
          transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.morph:hover > .pic{
-webkit-transform:translate(0px,-10px);
-webkit-filter:grayscale(100%) blur(1px);
}
.tooltip{
   background:rgba(80,80,80,0.5);
    color:black;
    z-index:10;
    display:none;
    position:absolute; 
    top:100px; 
    height:200px; 
    width:200px;
    margin-top:-100px;
}
.morph:hover > .tooltip{
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="Stylesheet" href="Stylesheet.css">
<div class="morph">
    <div class="pic">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/sports/1" alt="cricket">
    </div>
    <div class="tooltip">Lorem ipsum sit dolor am ecit, lorem ipsum sit dolor am ecit, I'm sure I got these wrong, but who cares  </div>
  </div>
```

You could do it like this :)

Answer (score 0):

I dont see any text that you want to show over there when hovering. But `:hover` is that to achieve this. So the answer is simply to provide tag element for the text you want to show and hide that, and then on hoverin, show the element. For example:

```
  <div class="imtex">
       <img src="some.jpg"/>
       <p>hi my text is here</p>
  </div>
```

So the style is:

```
    .imtex {
      display: block; 
      position: relative; //in case you want the child to absolute
     }

     .imtex img {
        display: block; 
        position:absolute; 
        z-index: 2; 
        top: 0; 
        bottom:0; 
        left:0; 
        right: 0;
     }

     .imtex p {
        display: none; 
        position:absolute; 
        z-index: 3; //after the image index 
        top: 0; 
        bottom:0; 
        left:0; 
        right: 0;
     }

    .imtex:hover p {
       display: block;
     }
```